# Error on launching application iOS 6

Tags: ios

I have an app build for iOS 5.0 and works fine running the same app on iOS 6 crashed on launch.

It seems to be crashing before calling didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

It's crashing as bad_excess on

```
0x00480848  <+0024>  ldr    r0, [pc, #240]  (0x48093c <_ZN6google8protobuf18InsertIfNotPresentISt3mapISsSt4pairIPKviESt4lessISsESaIS3_IKSsS6_EEESsS6_EEbPT_RKT0_RKT1_+268>)
0x0048084a  <+0026>  ldr    r1, [pc, #244]  (0x480940 <_ZN6google8protobuf18InsertIfNotPresentISt3mapISsSt4pairIPKviESt4lessISsESaIS3_IKSsS6_EEESsS6_EEbPT_RKT0_RKT1_+272>)
```

Comment: This should be discussed in the Apple Dev forums until the iOS6 SDK is live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following problems occur

1. Check you are clearly uninstall previous Xcode. if No Clearly un install the application.
2. Check the Mainwindow file is clearly linked to Files ownes.
3. Upgarade new xcode. not beta version.